# Add Double Quotes for String Column Value Separated With Comma And Write to CSV File With Comma Delimited

Tags: scala, apache-spark, azure-databricks

While writing data frame to file csv with comma delimited to some location, aim is to get string column value enclosed within double quotes and int column value without double quotes.

While writing data frame to csv file with comma delimited to some location, aim is to get string column value enclosed within double quotes and int column value without double quotes. 
Using below code,able to get expected results until got one column value separated with comma(e.g. "SOUTHERN GLAZES W&S OF CA, LOCAL").
In this case column Value is written to csv like :NUL"SOUTHERN GLAZERS W&S OF CA, NOCAL"NUL.
When tried with pipe("|") delimited getting proper result but need output with comma delimited.

### Table structure:

```
%sql
CREATE TABLE A.dummy_table
(
col1 string,
col2 string,
col3 int
)
```

### Table Data:

```
%sql
insert into A.dummy_table values('A','B',1),('C','D',2),('SOUTHERN GLAZERS W&S OF CA, NOCAL','DOWE AVE',1234)

%sql
select* from A.dummy_table

col 1   col 2   col 3
SOUTHERN GLAZES W&S OF CA, LOCAL    DOE AVE 1234
A   B   1
C   D   2
```

### Transforming table data Into Data frame:

```
var df = spark.sql("select * from A.dummy_table")
```

### Code to add quotes on String column Value and remove quotes for Int column Value:

```
var df_new = df.select(df.columns.map(x =>concat(lit("\""),col(x),lit("\"")) as x):_*)
val int_columns = df.dtypes.filter(_._2 !="StringType").map(_._1)
for(colName<-int_columns)
{
df_new = df_new.withColumn(colName,regexp_replace(col(colName),"\"",""))
}

df_new.coalesce(1).write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").mode("overwrite").option("ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace",false).option("ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace",false).option("header", "true").option("quote","\u0000").option("delimiter",",").save("somePath")
val fileNm = dbutils.fs.ls("somePath").map(_.name).filter(r => r.startsWith("part-00000"))(0)
dbutils.fs.mv("somePath"+"/"+fileNm,"someFinalPath")
dbutils.fs.rm("somePath",true)
```

### Expected Result :

```
col1,col2,col3
"SOUTHERN GLAZERS W&S OF CA, NOCAL","DOWE AVE",1234
"A","B",1
"C","D",2
```

### Actual Result

```
col1,col2,col3
NUL"SOUTHERN GLAZERS W&S OF CA, NOCAL"NUL,"DOWE AVE",1234
"A","B",1
"C","D",2
```

Comment: why did you add this part - this looks like it is quoting with NUL(L)s? `option("quote","\u0000")`

Comment: Without quote option column values will have extra \”,so to avoid this we have to use quote option.